# Navigation bar sometimes disappears on iOS using Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have run into a strange issue using Salesforce1 for iOS devices. It appears that the Navigation Bar sometimes disappears when the User interacts with the application. This does not happen all the time and it appears to be very random. I have added a couple of print screen on how it looks when it is OK and when the issue arises. The issue only arises on iOS devices, Android runs fine.

I have tested with a variation of iOS versions but mainly 8.4, I cannot see any connection between the issues and anything else but iOS in general.

**iPhon OK:**

### [image: iPhone OK]

**iPad issue:**

### [image: iPad Issue]

**iPhone issue:**

### [image]

Has anyone else experienced this and can point towards a Known issue or a implementable solution? Any help is highly appreciated!

Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a known issue. See here for details: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jauJAAQ